# Problem with input from simple script that copies a file to a different directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cp

As someone trying to learn bash, I have been making simple scripts to test out various commands. In the following simple script, I am experimenting with the read command.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a path to a file: " file_to_copy
cp $file_to_copy /tmp
```

If the user enters the entire path to a test file e.g. /home/$USER/test when prompted, the script executes as expected and makes a copy of "test" in the /tmp directory. However, if the user enters the shorthand ~/test, terminal returns the error *cp: cannot stat '~/test': No such file or directory.* Why is the command cp unable to find an equivalent representation of the file path when entered?

If I independently enter in terminal:

```
cp ~/test /tmp
```

the test file is copied without incident, so it is probably a nuance of  variable assignment that I messed up, but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that you literally ask shell to find `~/test` from the directory the script is currently in. In other words, if you run from `/home/$USER`, it will be looking for file `test` in subdirectory named `~`, not the expansion `/home/$USER/test`.

What you can use is `bash`'s eval built in, which will take any arguments and put them together as one command and let the shell run it. Now, shell will expand `~`.

```
xieerqi:
$ ./copyScript.sh                                                                                                       
Enter a path to a file: ~/test
Entered /home/xieerqi/test

xieerqi:
$ ls -l /tmp/test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 Dec 21 01:14 /tmp/test

xieerqi:
$ cat copyScript.sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a path to a file: " file_to_copy
file_to_copy=$(eval echo $file_to_copy)
echo "Entered $file_to_copy"
cp "$file_to_copy" /tmp
```

I'd suggest you also use quotes around the command-substitution `$( . . .)` , to ensure that files with spaces in them and special character will be properly captured into `file_to_copy` variable

**ADDITION**

As stated in the comments, `eval` built-in can be dangerous.

Personally, I use the `readlink` command quite often in my scripts and avoid using `~`. And since in this script you ask for user input anyway, why not use command line arguments ? Like so:

```
xieerqi:
$ ./copyScript.sh testFile.txt                                
/home/xieerqi/testFile.txt

xieerqi:
$ cat copyScript.sh                                           
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$(readlink -f "$@" )"

echo $FILE
# uncomment for copying
# cp $FILE /tmp
```

**dirname and basename**

GNU coreutils provides two commands, `basename` and `dirname`. `basename` shows last element in the path , and `dirname` shows everything preceding last element. One could use `bash`'s internal parameter expansion to do the same, but since we have these tools - why not use them:

```
xieerqi:
$ ./copyScript.sh                                             
Enter path to file: ~/testFile.txt
File entered is  /home/xieerqi/testFile.txt

xieerqi:
$ ./copyScript.sh                                             
Enter path to file: ~/sumFile.txt
File entered is  /home/xieerqi/sumFile.txt
ERROR, file doesn't exist

xieerqi:
$ cat copyScript.sh                                           
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter path to file: " FILEPATH

DIRPATH="$(dirname "$FILEPATH")"
FILENAME="$(basename "$FILEPATH" )"

if [ "$DIRPATH" == "~"   ];then
  DIRPATH="$HOME"
fi

FILEPATH="$DIRPATH"/"$FILENAME"
echo "File entered is " "$FILEPATH"

[ -e "$FILEPATH"  ] || { echo "ERROR, file doesn't exist"; exit 1;}
```

Comment: Alright. I can understand that. I don't have enough rep to upvote these responses, but I'll come back when I do. Thanks for the explanation, guys.

Comment: @mike3759 Note that this should be used carefully. Running `eval` on an arbitrary string this way allows code injection. To make an example, if the script had to run some `sudo` commands for a non-sudoer user and was setup in `/etc/sudoers` to not require the `sudo` password, enetering `$(exec sudo -i)` would have given root access to the non-sudoer user.

Comment: I'll remember that. I found a program on github that allows me to compile .sh scripts that I write and make them executables. I also found out through some guesswork that placing the executable in /usr/bin makes it runable as a command in terminal. To avoid the problem you brought up, couldn't I just not specify any sudo commands in my script, and make the user input something like "sudo mycommand" into terminal? It works that way with commands such as "apt-get", no? You can't run that command without being a super user.

Comment: @mike3759 scripts don't need to be compiled, they are executable once you do `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh` Whatever that program was, I'd suggest you get rid of it. Also, you don't need to necessarily to place them into `/usr/bin`. You just need to change a few things in `$HOME/.profile` file and have personal `$HOME/bin` folder

Answer (score 4):

Try these commands in your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a path to a file: " file_to_copy
file_to_copy=$(bash -c "echo $file_to_copy")
file_to_copy=${file_to_copy/~\//$HOME\/}
cp "${file_to_copy}" /tmp
```

Explanation:

- The third line will expand `env` variable values if any present.
- The fourth line in the above code will try to search for `~` in your `file_to_copy` variable and if found it will be replace by `$HOME` path.
- And `\/` here `\` is a backslash escape sequence character for `/`, as we want to replace `~/` with `$HOME/`.

Comment: That works. Thanks. You explained that it is searching for the ~ symbol in your response, but can you explain the commands that do that? I don't understand the series of back and forward slashes you used in the variable reassignment of line 3. How does that series of slashes translate to searching for a ~?

Comment: @kos `bash -c "echo $file_to_copy"` this will expand the env variables values from the `file_to_copy` variable, thanks for correction.

Comment: @snoop although this works, this is also has security danger , same as `eval`  in my answer. Using ` `sudo -i` ` also allows gaining access to root shell. Note the two asterisks

Comment: Another thing, you should probably replace just the tilde (not assuming that it's going to be followed by `/`, since if the path entered is just `~` the tilde won't be replaced) and only when it's at the start, since e.g. `/home/foo/~` is a file named `~` in the home directory, and replacing the tilde would obviously break the path.

Comment: @Serg Where do you think there's a security flaw exactly?

Comment: @kos Here:http://paste.ubuntu.com/14126465/ Arbitrary command execution possible with echo and backticks

Comment: @Serg Ah indeed. What Serg said as well. I have no idea how you could solve that though.

Comment: The more I ponder this question, the more it seems that tilde expansion is best left to interactive shell use and not scripts

Comment: This idea for this script came from: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Chapter_3_answers that I am using to learn bash. They have a different solution if you want to look at that. Question #8

Comment: @Serg I tried `function abs_path {  (cd "$(dirname '$1')" &>/dev/null && printf "%s/%s" "$PWD" "${1##*/}")}` to expand path from script but its not working though its working fine in terminal.

Comment: Yeah, because when you call `abs_path $file_to_copy` , that `file_to_copy` is still a `~/test.txt` string, the tilde not being expanded

Comment: Hey, guys !  I've played around with dirname and basename a little. Check the edit